# Move Product Title on Single Product Page above Images on Mobile Only (woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce I just want to know How can I move the product title above the images for Mobile only?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rFuD.png

I tried the following code but not working.

```
jQuery( function($) {

  mobile = $(window).width();
  if ( mobile <= 480 ){
    jQuery( ".product_title.entry-title" ).insertBefore( ".woocommerce-product-gallery" );
  }

} );
```

Comment: share what is the output you getting it.

Comment: First of all you have to check your J-query code is working or not? print console.log('TEST') after if condition.

Comment: Yes, the code is not executing

Comment: Code working now. I just put it inside footer.php file